# How to use Selenium's PageFactory annotations with dynamic loaded elements?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, test-design, page-objects

I'm rewriting some Selenium tests according to the page object design pattern taking advantage of [Seleniums' annotations](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory#Making_the_Example_Work_Using_Annotations). My problem is that I have some html `select` elements whose `option` elements are loaded dynamically. These are not available at the same time the `select`s are.

The original code looks like:

```
public void fillinForm() {
    // Fill-in some fields ...

    // Select dynamic loaded option
    String optionXpath = "//*[@id='field']/option[text()='Software engineering']";
    waitForElement(driver, By.xpath(optionXpath), SHORT_TIMEOUT_S);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(optionXpath)).click();

    // Fill-in more fields, etc ...
}

// Selenium wait
public static void waitForElement(WebDriver driver, By by, int timeout) {
    // implementation
}
```

The new code turns into something like:

```
public void setUp() {
    page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Page.class);
}

public void fillinForm() {
    page.setField("Software engineering");
}

public class Page {
    private webElement field;

    public Page setField(String byText) {
        field.click();
        String optionXpath = String.format("./option[text()='%s']", byText);
        field.findElement(By.xpath(optionXpath)).click();
        return this;
    }
}
```

If I want to implement the wait in the new code, I have to use an xpath for the `option` that includes the xpath for the `select`, thus losing the advantage of using annotations to simplify the code:

```
public void fillinForm() {
    page.setField("Software engineering");
}

public class Page {
    private webElement field;

    public Page setField(String byText) {
        field.click();
        // Note that I'm now explicitly writing "field", exactly what I wanted
        // to save using annotations and the PageFactory
        String optionXpath = String.format("//select[@id='%s']/option[text()='%s']",
            "field", byText);
        field.findElement(By.xpath(optionXpath)).click();
        return this;
    }
}
```

Is there any annotation I can use to wait until the options are loaded, or am I using this wrong?

Answer (score 4):

After spending some more time with [WebDriverWait](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html), I came out with something nicer:

Client code:

```
/** Page Object. */
public class Page {
    private WebElement mySelect;

    public Page setMySelect(String optionText) {
        String optXpath = String.format("./option[text()='%s']", optionText);
        mySelect.click();
        waitForOption(driver,mySelect, By.xpath(optXpath), 10)
            .click();
    }
}
```

Utility library:

```
public class Util {

    /**
     * Waits until the option targeted by <tt>byOption</tt> is available.
     *
     * @param select parent element of the option to wait for
     * @param byOption selector (relative to the <tt>select</tt>). It will be
     *             searched calling <tt>select.findElement(byOption)</tt>
     * @return option element
     */
    public static WebElement waitForOption(
            WebDriver driver, WebElement select, By byOption, int seconds) {
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, seconds);
        return wait.until(new OptionAvailable(select, byOption));

    }

    public static class OptionAvailable
            implements ExpectedCondition<WebElement> {
        private WebElement select;
        private By byOption;

        public OptionAvailable(WebElement select, By byOption) {
            this.select = select;
            this.byOption = byOption;
        }

        @Override
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver input) {
            return select.findElement(byOption);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that with this approach (a `By` for the option), we can support the option as text or as value.

Comment: I'm testing it now, and it seems that it doesn't work :-( The two consecutive clicks (in select and in option) are failing somehow, and unfortunately it is not easy to debug, as the debugger interferes with the normal flow.

Comment: Indeed, it works removing the `mySelect.click()`. I'm a bit confused now, as I was "double"-clicking due to [Selenium's issue 2112](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2112). I have to check if without this "double" click it still works in my _SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11_ box with _Firefox 3.6.18_